# How to Manual update database fields after auto migration with entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a MVC project with entity framework in automatic migrations and trying to figure out how to update the database after new properties have been added.

I have this scenario.

Before:

```
public class X {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public bool IsChecked() {
        ... // some heavy duty routine
    }
}
```

The code has been released and is working on the production environment but slow so I want to cache the method IsChecked. I alter my class:

```
public class X {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public bool Checked {get;set;}

    public bool SetChecked() {
        bool result = ... // some heavy duty routine
        Checked = result;
    }
}
```

Now I want to make an update script which executes the SetChecked on all items in the database.

What approach should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If migration is enabled and set to auto, all you need to do is to add a new migration, in vs just open package-manager console and select the project from the drop down list and type this command:

add-migration "name-of-migration"

this will create a new class under migrations folder then you have to compile and upload new code to the server. After the first query the database will be updated.

Comment: Didn't know when using auto migration you could still add a migration yourself. Thanks!